# Chrome shows source of webpage instead of the Application layout.

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

We have an internal web application that renders fine in IE 8 when login. But in chrome, it shows the page source like:

```
 <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript">
    {  ..... }</SCRIPT>

    <HTML>
        <HEAD><TITLE>Blah</TITLE>
    <LINK HREF="printDUC.css" REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css">

    <!-- calendar stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/MCPS/theme/calendar-win2k-cold-1.css" title="win2k-cold-1" />

    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript 1.5" type="text/JavaScript" SRC="/MCPS/js/print.js"></SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<!-- VARIOUS HTML Tags like TABLE etc -->
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Tried debugging with developer console. The response tab has the text that is shown in Chrome. The HTTP response header has:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 07 Mar 2013 15:49:48 GMT
Server: IBM_HTTP_Server
Keep-Alive: timeout=10, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Language: en-US
```

Is the content-type text/plain causing this issue? Wondering why it would render the components fine in IE 8. Firefox behavior is same as chrome.

Comment: What does the actual full source of the page look like?

Comment: The view source page appears to be the same as the rendered page.

Comment: Then your HTML is invalid; doesn't even have a doctype or a html start tag. Try running it through a validator to get a valid HTML page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the "Content-Type: text/plain" is the problem, it should be:

```
Content-Type: text/html
```

in the Respone header to be rendered by Chrome.